# Parse.com doesNotMatchKeyInQuery not working with objectId and pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to return a list a users who are not already in a friends join table on Parse.com but it seems that trying to match a pointer record with a users objectId will not work.

We could break this out into separate calls but that would be poor performance.

Has anyone solved this yet?

```
//Get users current friends
var myfriends = new Parse.Query("UserFriend");
myfriends.equalTo("myUserId",user);

//get users who are not already friends
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "theirUserId", myfriends);
userQuery.find().then(function(newfriends){
  //do stuff with newfriends
  //New friends should not include existing friends but it does..
});
```

Big thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: so you stored string ids instead of pointers to the user objects?

Comment: I have an idea and will post an answer.. it would be to have a query for Parse.User that *matches* key in query for user friends, against a user query that does not match *that* query :).. it's worth trying/testing..

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to seeing a solution.  I've been researching this and haven't yet found a working query for pointers in join tables

Comment: Did anybody come up with a decent solution that wasn't performing the arrays separate and extracting all the object ids of the pointers into an array to use not/containedIn?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but give it a shot..  From my comment: "have a query for Parse.User that matches key in query for user friends, against a user query that does not match that query".  This might suffer the same problem.

```
var friendsQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
var myfriends = new Parse.Query("UserFriend");
myfriends.equalTo("myUserId",user);
friendsQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "theirUserId", myfriends);

var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.doesNotMatchQuery("objectId", friendsQuery);
//Assuming Cloud Code...
userQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(newfriends){
  //do stuff with newfriends
});
```

Comment: Hey Fosco, thanks for trying.  Could not get it to work I've so ended up creating a field with the ObjectId as a string rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work either.. Instead I used doesNotMatchQuery which worked find with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and discovered you can't compare an *objectId* to a pointer object. So in the case above:

```
userQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "theirUserId", myfriends);
```

*theirUserId* would need to be a string key containing the the actual alphanumeric Id, not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a running issue in Parse Server
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4346

Comment: Please provide a comment. This is not an answer